# How to correctly use template tags in this specific Many-to-Many relationship in Django?

Tags: django, data-structures, many-to-many

I've got the following Django many-to-many through model setup, but I can't seem to figure out how to iterate through each *Container*, get the list of checkboxes and if those checkboxes are true or false (CheckboxStatus.status).

The models are:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    checkboxes = models.ManyToManyField('Checkbox',
                                        through='CheckboxStatus',
                                        related_name='containers')

class Checkbox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class CheckboxStatus(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container,
                                          related_name='checkboxstatus')
    checkbox = models.ForeignKey(Checkbox, related_name='checkboxstatus')
    status = models.NullBooleanField()
```

I've got the following where *object_list* = the *CheckboxStatus* model  ...

```
{% for object in object_list. %}
    {{ object.container }}
    {{ object.checkbox }}
    {{ object.status }}
{% endfor %}
```

... but this results in all checkboxes, and I need to do some operations on each *Container*. In pseudocode, I'd like to have:

```
for container in object_list (where objectlist is "container"):
    container.id
    container.checkbox.id
    container.checkbox.status (unique for the container.id)
```

But maybe the relation is just plain wrong. Can some one push me in the right direction?

Comment: Also, what resources would you recommend to learn about these kind of database structures? I can't seem to grasp the concept of these more complex database relations quite yet.

Comment: Is your Checkbox model supposed to be a checkbox on a form? Like a list of Options for a Container that can be selected via a checkbox?

Comment: Hi @RobVezina ! Yes, what I would like to do is: have multiple "sea containers", a << container >> model , give each one a list of checkboxes (checkbox) as defined in the << checkbox >> model, and have a << status >> for those << checkboxes >> for each << container >>. I probably have a wrong database relationship model, I guess? Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, I don't think you need the through table. You should be able to define the [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) and then use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) and a [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) widget to display the options as checkboxes.

I changed the models to:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    options = models.ManyToManyField('Option')

# I changed the name of the Checkbox model to Option, for clarity.
class Option(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

from forms.py:

```
class ContainerOptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Container
    fields = ['options']

    widgets = {
        'options': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }
```

Include the options form field in your template:

```
{{ form.options }}
```

If you need more control over the display of the options checkboxes, you can iterate over the options field of the form:

```
{% for checkbox in form.options %}
    <label>{{ checkbox.choice_label }} {{ checkbox.tag }}</label>    
{% endfor %}
```

This should take care of it for a single container on a page. If you need to handle multiple containers on the same page, you will need to look into [ModelFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Ah, that's even better than my fix below! Thanks Rob, this teaches me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

Model code:

```
class ContainerBox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CheckBox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    containerbox = models.ManyToManyField(
        ContainerBox, through="CheckBoxStatus")

class CheckboxStatus(models.Model):
    containerbox = models.ForeignKey(ContainerBox, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    checkbox = models.ForeignKey(CheckBox, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.NullBooleanField()
```

and template code:

```
{% for containerbox in object_list %}
    <h2>name: {{containerbox.name}}</h2>

    {% for checkboxstatus in containerbox.checkboxstatus_set.all %}
        {{ checkboxstatus.status}} ({{ checkboxstatus.checkbox }})<br/>

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This does what I need it to do: iterate over containers, then over checkboxes. I just swapped checkboxes and checkboxstatuses.